# Are propositions considered to be mind independent or mind dependent?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

The primary reason why I ask is to try to contrast the concept of a proposition, with that of a fact, the latter with which I more certain about. A fact, to me, is something that is 100% mind-independent, is always true, always discovered, and tells us something about reality, unless trivial (like the tautological statement all wives are married).

A proposition though, seems to be in part a linguistic construct, that encodes a belief about something, which is why they can be false, for we are fallible beings and can at times be wrong about our assertions. Propositions thus to me seem to be mind-dependent, and if so, would be a construction derived from the human-mind expressed by way of language.

However, I am less certain about where I stand with propositions than I am with facts. Facts to me are more concrete (literally and figuratively), though propositions seem to take on a much more abstract nature. So some clarification and/or validation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "X is a fact" is a proposition, not a fact. How can we assess facts in their "factical" purity, if we only can talk about them in language?

Comment: On the standard view facts are propositions that happen to be empirically true. Due to the nature of "empirically" your "something that is 100% mind-independent, is always true..." does not exist in this world. What propositions themselves are is a controversial issue in semantics, the idea is for them to be the public "meanings" of declarative sentences, that is non-psychological somethings that can be communicated and are capable of being true or false. There is no consensus as to what the nature of such "meanings" might be.